# Mysql error

Tags: php, mysql

session_start();
include 'inc/db.php';
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$nick = $_POST['nick'];
$password2 = $_POST['pass2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$avatar = "no_avatar";
$key = session_id();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ls = 85;
$score = 0;
$lscore = 0;
$rating = 0;
$car = "Mersedes_W123";
$carname = "Mersedes_W123";
$reg_date = date("Y-m-n H:i:s");
$dolar = 15000;
$fuel = 100;
$level = 1;
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO users (login,password,nick,email,ls,rating,car,carname,lscore,key,reg_date,ip,dolar,fuel,level,avatar) VALUES('$login','$password','$nick','$email','$ls','$rating','$car','$carname','$lscore','$key','$reg_date','$ip','$dolar','$fuel','$level','$avatar')") or die(mysql_error());
if ($result2 == TRUE)
{
$session_id = session_id();
echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Ваш ключ для восстановления пароля! $session_id";
}

выдает ошибку You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key,reg_date,ip,dolar,fuel,level,avatar) VALUES('admin','sacsd','Admin','admin@m' at line 1

помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
session_start();
include 'inc/db.php'; 
$login = $_POST['login']; 
$password = $_POST['pass']; 
$nick = $_POST['nick']; 
$password2 = $_POST['pass2']; 
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$avatar = "no_avatar"; 
$key = session_id();
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ls = 85;
$score = 0;
$lscore = 0;
$rating = 0;
$car = "Mersedes_W123";
$carname = "Mersedes_W123";
$reg_date = date("Y-m-n H:i:s");
$dolar = 15000; 
$fuel = 100; 
$level = 1; 
$result2 = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`,`password`,`nick`,`email`,`ls`,`rating`,`car`,`carname`,`lscore`,`key`,`reg_date`,`ip`,`dolar`,`fuel`,`level`,`avatar`) VALUES('$login','$password','$nick','$email','$ls','$rating','$car','$carname','$lscore','$key','$reg_date','$ip','$dolar','$fuel','$level','$avatar')") or die(mysql_error()); if ($result2 == TRUE) { $session_id = session_id(); echo "Вы успешно зарегистрированы! Ваш ключ для восстановления пароля! $session_id"; }
```

Проверяйте, кстати, у Вас уязвимый код, прочитайте про sql-инъекции

Comment: спасибо огромное заработало! и про инъекцию прочитаю! ))))

Comment: Удачи, Вам. Обращайтесь)